# how to store and retrieve and delete a list in documetDB using c#

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to know how to store and retrieve list in Document DB.
I am having a list and then i need to serialize the list into json object and store into Document DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-dotnet-application/). DocumentDb makes it very easy to save any object, it even does the JSON serialization automatically for you.

Comment: You just posted a link (which is discouraged) vs an actual explanation/answer. Also, you linked to a page about designing an entire asp.net mvc application, not a page specifically about working with lists.

Comment: @David, it is obvious that little to no research has been done on the subject.

Comment: I have no idea what you're referring to, @Mikee, aside from the OP maybe not researching the subject. But I'm trying to share some guidance to you on what types of answers survive (or don't survive) on StackOverflow. Link-only answers are usually deleted. Links to pages that are not directly related to the question? They're often deleted as well. At best, your link should be a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sudheer - are you trying to take JSON as a string and store it in DocumentDB or store an object? The .Net samples show how to do the latter but in short you can create a List of POCO objects then iterate through them, writing them to the DB. Alternatively if you want separate JSON documents to be written as a single transaction you can write a stored procedure to so this.

Here's an example with a POCO List. Note that in the definition of SalesOrder definition the property has an attribute to map it to database id:

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")] 
public string Id { get; set; }

var orders = new List();

```
        orders.Add(new SalesOrder 
        { 
            Id = "POCO1", 
            PurchaseOrderNumber = "PO18009186470", 
            OrderDate = new DateTime(2005, 7, 1), 
            AccountNumber = "10-4020-000510", 
            SubTotal = 419.4589m, 
            TaxAmt = 12.5838m, 
            Freight = 472.3108m, 
            TotalDue = 985.018m, 
            Items = new[] 
            { 
                new SalesOrderDetail 
                { 
                    OrderQty = 1, 
                    ProductId = 760, 
                    UnitPrice = 419.4589m, 
                    LineTotal = 419.4589m 
                } 
            }, 
        }); 

        orders.Add(new SalesOrder2 
        { 
            Id = "POCO2", 
            PurchaseOrderNumber = "PO15428132599", 
            OrderDate = new DateTime(2005, 7, 1), 
            DueDate = new DateTime(2005, 7, 13), 
            ShippedDate = new DateTime(2005, 7, 8), 
            AccountNumber = "10-4020-000646", 
            SubTotal = 6107.0820m, 
            TaxAmt = 586.1203m, 
            Freight = 183.1626m, 
            DiscountAmt = 1982.872m,            
            TotalDue = 4893.3929m, 
            Items = new[] 
            { 
                new SalesOrderDetail2 
                { 
                    OrderQty = 3, 
                    ProductCode = "A-123",       
                    ProductName = "Product 1",  
                    CurrencySymbol = "$",       
                    CurrencyCode = "USD",       
                    UnitPrice = 17.1m,            
                    LineTotal = 5.7m  
                }, 
            } 
        }); 

        foreach (var order in orders) 
        { 
            Document created = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(colSelfLink, order); 
            Console.WriteLine("Created SalesOrder: " + created); 
        }
```